# Problem when testing via @DataJpaTest with composite key entities

Tags: spring-data-jpa, composite-key, data-jpa-test

I'm trying to test an entity that I've mapped with a composite key.

Simply, I tried to test from the Repository layer, but the desired data and results did not come out.

I don't use `@CreationTimestamp` very often, so you don't have to mention this part, but if this part is a problem,

please mention it.

Please take into account typos.  Thanks.

The code looks like this:

```java
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Getter
@IdClass(TestId.class)
@ToString
public class TestEntity  {

    @Id
    private Long groupCode;

    @Id
    private Long code;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private LocalDateTime regDate;

    @UpdateTimestamp
    @Column(insertable = false)
    private LocalDateTime modDate;

    public TestEntity(Long groupCode, Long code) {
        this.groupCode = groupCode;
        this.code = code;
    }
}
```

Repository

```java
public interface TestEnttiyRepository extends JpaRepository<TestEntity, TestId> {
}
```

Composite-id Class

```java
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class TestId implements Serializable {

    private Long groupCode;
    private Long code;

    public TestId(Long groupCode, Long code) {
        this.groupCode = groupCode;
        this.code = code;
    }
}
```

```java
@DataJpaTest
class TestEnttiyRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestEnttiyRepository testEnttiyRepository;

    @Commit
    @Test
    void test() {
        TestEntity testEntity = new TestEntity(1L, 1L);

        TestEntity save = testEnttiyRepository.save(testEntity);
        System.out.println("save = " + save);
    }

}
```

Test Result

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        testentity0_.code as code1_5_0_,
        testentity0_.group_code as group_co2_5_0_,
        testentity0_.mod_date as mod_date3_5_0_,
        testentity0_.reg_date as reg_date4_5_0_ 
    from
        test_entity testentity0_ 
    where
        testentity0_.code=? 
        and testentity0_.group_code=?
save = TestEntity(groupCode=1, code=1, regDate=null, modDate=null)
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        test_entity
        (reg_date, code, group_code) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?)
```

Currently my question here is this.

1. The order of the output value through `System.out.println` and the `insert query` through save is reversed.
2. The `LocalDateTime` was not added automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The order of the output value through `System.out.println` and the insert query through save is reversed.

`Repository.save` just as `EntityManager.persist` don't save anything.
They just make entities *managed* which will result in them being saved when a *flush* happens, which is at the end of the transaction, which in turn is at the end of your method, so after the `System.out` statement.

Comment: Thank you for answer.
The conclusion on this matter was made during the day.
As you said, the transaction was applied to the entire test code by @DataJpaTest, and if you think about the inner workings of JPA for a moment, it was an issue that would be resolved quickly.

Comment: Glad my answer was helpful. The customary way to say thank you over here at SO is to upvote and accept answers.